# Full text search query not returning result in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have created a catalog and fulltext index for my table as :

```
create fulltext catalog testsearch

select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON test_master

(name)
KEY INDEX PK_test_master
ON testsearch
```

But when I try to retrieve values as

```
select * from test_master where contains(name, 'product')
```

The query just returns me the columns of the table 'test_master' but no rows are populated.. I'm not getting any error either.. plz help me

Comment: Are you sure that table is having any record with word `product`?.. Remember, it will match only the whole word, not part of the word...

Comment: may be your full-text index has not been populated yet.. Goto SSMS > right click on your table > Full-index.. > Start population

Comment: yes my table has a row with column 'name' having value 'product and i have tried populating my full text index but its still not working..

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your table size, indexing might take some time. You may wait a little before running your queries.

I tend to script population like this ( Must confess I didn't know it could be done with user interface...)

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON test_master START FULL POPULATION
```

I also use to manually set the change traking auto after that, though it is the default behaviour (don't remember why. I must have encountered some issues once...)

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON test_master SET CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
```